# Limit of: $\cos(x) + \sin(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x)\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

From playing around with a graph, I noticed that:

$$
\lim_{a \to \infty}
\sum_{n=0}^{a}
      \left( \sin \left( x-\frac{\pi }{2} \right) \right)^n
      \cos \left( x-\frac{\pi }{2} \right) 
  \approx \tan \left( 0.5x \right)
$$

Can anyone prove this?

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric progression?

Comment: @MarkBennet, it is written with the argument of sine raised to a power.  So it's not geometric.

Comment: @Paul Actually, the notation is ambiguous... It'd make sense for the OP to clarify this point.

Comment: @Paul Then the title of the post needs to be changed.

Comment: @Paul that is actually a good question - on the other hand I am pretty sure that not the argument was meant but rather the whole function (otherwise there would be no convergence whatsoever be possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sin \left( x-\frac\pi2\right)=-\sin \left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=-\cos x$$

$$\cos \left( x-\frac\pi2 \right)=\cos \left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\sin x$$

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^a\sin \left( x-\frac\pi2\right)^n\cos \left(x-\frac\pi2\right) $$

$$=\sin x\sum_{n=0}^a(-\cos x)^n$$
$$=\sin x\cdot\dfrac{1-(-\cos x)^{a+1}}{1+\cos x}$$

Now for real $x,|\cos x|\le1$ and for $x\ne2m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer, $|-\cos x|<1$

$$\implies\lim_{a\to\infty}(-\cos x)^{a+1}\to0$$

$$\implies\lim_{a\to\infty}S=\dfrac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\dfrac{2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2}{2\cos^2\dfrac x2}=?$$